# How to change string to date without converting to any timezone in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I know there are lot of questions passing around over this simple issue, but still I couldn't get a clear idea.

Here is what I want:

```
SelectedDateString = "19-08-2015 09:00 AM"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm a"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone();
let SelectedUTCDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(SelectedDateString)!
println("SelectedLocalDate = \(SelectedLocalDate)") 
// OUTPUT: SelectedLocalDate = 2015-08-18 18:30:00 +0000
```

If I dont use TimeZone:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm a"
// dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone();
let SelectedUTCDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(SelectedDateString)!
println("SelectedLocalDate = \(SelectedLocalDate)")
//OUTPUT: SelectedLocalDate = 2015-08-18 19:26:00 +0000
```

Why is there change in the time and Date? What I want is:

```
//OUTPUT: SelectedLocalDate = 2015-08-19 09:00:00 +0000
```

Also I want to convert the Local Date to Exact UTC Date

```
//Like this: SelectedUTCDate = 2015-08-19 03:30:00 

inputString = "19-08-2015 10:45 am"  // My localtime is 10:35 AM, so I set 10 mins from now
 var currentUTCTime = NSDate() // currentUTCTime is 05: 15 AM.
```

I want to convert the inputString to its respective UTC Time and find the difference between the two times in both date and string.

```
//Like this Date: diffInDate: 00-00-0000 00:10 and
// Like this String: diffInString: 10 mins
```

How can I get both of these?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
let dateString = "19-08-2015 09:00 AM"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"
if let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
    print(dateFromString)   // "2015-08-19 09:00:00 +0000"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a Z"
    dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromString)  // 19-08-2015 06:00 AM -0300"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That works!!! And to change that to equal UTC time? 2015-08-19 03:30:00 +0000

Comment: Please see my edited Question. I want to convert an input time to its respective UTC time and find the difference between them in both date and string

Comment: Is your input UTC or localTime ?

Comment: both of them actually.

Comment: NSDate is a point in time. There is no timezone stored in a NSDate object. You need to specify the timezone for your date to be displayed

Comment: Got it Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 1):

```
extension Date {
    func originToString(dateFormat: String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
        dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```